# Making a sprite move based on its rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, unityscript

I am new to Unity2D and I am trying to get my sprite to move based on the direction it is facing.  I was able to get the rotation based on pressing A or the D key but when it comes to moving forward based on which direction my sprite is facing I am running into errors

My current code :

```
#pragma strict

var moveForward : KeyCode;
var turnRight : KeyCode;
var turnLeft : KeyCode;
var fire : KeyCode;

var speed : float = 4;
var turnSpeed : float = 2;

function Update () {

// When the user wants to jet pulse forward.
if(Input.GetKey(moveForward)){

    // NEEDS FIXING HERE!!! <<<<<
    rigidbody2D.velocity.x = Mathf.Cos(rigidbody2D.rotation) * speed;
    rigidbody2D.velocity.y = Mathf.Sin(rigidbody2D.rotation) * speed;

}

// When we rotate the sprite.
if(Input.GetKey(turnRight)){

    transform.Rotate(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);

}else if(Input.GetKey(turnLeft)){

    transform.Rotate(0.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f);

}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can probably simply use this:

```
rigidbody2D.velocity = (Vector2)transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.up) * speed;
```

Comment: Thank you for the input as it help me come to my conclusion on what I was looking for :).

Comment: No problem. I said "probably" because I thought that it depends on your GameObject set up. On really simple test scene my code seem to work fine. BTW, you could mark your own answer as correct one so every one knows that you have already found the answer.

Comment: For the checking my own answer it is telling me I cannot do it until tomorrow lol.

Answer (score 1):

What I was looking for was this:

```
rigidbody2D.AddForce(transform.up);
```

Instead of doing all the angle calculation myself (which was very buggy) this works just find in moving in the direction based on which way your sprite is facing.

But also to put in here, my sprite at angle/rotation.z = 0 was when my sprite was LOOKING literally up towards the top of the computer screen.  If you have your initial sprite looking somewhere else other than UP then you will have to adjust the transform.up -> -transform.right, transform.right, or -transform.up for correct results.